# How to find records with minimum value in a specific column in multiple files?

Tags: awk

I have 2 column 4000 dat files. from each file, I need to identify first mimum value of column 2 and print corresponding row. Then this should run   on multiple files in the folder and append these values to a new file. I have tried below code.

File names include common string:

```
fig_3-28333.dat
      ^^^^^ file number
```

```
awk'BEGIN{min=0}{if(($2)>min)  min=($2)}END {print line}' cat >> new.dat
```

output file expected to be

```
file number Column 1 column2
28333           x value  first minimum value
28334           x value  first minimum value
```

Comment: Your script will find **maximum** value in column 2 but print nothing since `line` is unset. And it's unclear how files should be numbered, I mean what makes a file 1st?

Comment: file names are fig_3-0.2833.gfs.dat , so common name will be fig_3-*.dat. I tried with sort and awk  as given below. sort is giving for given file but I am not sure how to run it on multiple files so trying with awk. for file in *.dat;
do
 
 
sort -nk 2 $file | head -n 1  > new.dat
#awk  'BEGIN{min=0}{if(($2)>min)  min=($2)}END {print line \n}' sample.dat
done.

Comment: It is not giving any output. but when I apply sort on terminal for a file, I am getting the minimum valued line

Comment: I need column1 and column 2 which are minimum values of each file. If can get number from file name   fig_3-0.2833.gfs.dat. It will be wonderful.

Comment: condition on column 2 for minimum and print row.

Comment: see my answer, and tell me if it works or not, or if you have a question about how it works etc.

Comment: Of course it's not printing anything (other than a single newline).  `line` is unset in the END block.  If you want to print something, you should print the line that you selected as containing the minimum value.  Try `awk 'NR==1{min=$2}$2 <= min{min=$2; line=$0} END {print line}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE: This only works with `gawk` (which understands the `ENDFILE` pattern), and not the regular `awk`**

Here is my script, *min.awk*:

```
BEGIN {
    print "file number Column 1 column2"
}

FNR == 1 {
    min = $2;
    first = $1
    second = $2
}

$2 < min {
    min = $2
    first = $1
    second = $2
}

ENDFILE {
    # Extract the file number to a[1]
    match(FILENAME, /.*-([0-9]+)\.dat/, a)  
    print a[1], first, second
}
```

## Notes

- The `BEGIN` pattern prints the heading
- At the first line of each file (pattern: `FNR == 1`), establish the minimum value
- For those lines whose second value is less than the minimum (pattern: `$2 < min`), establish the new minimum value
- At the end of each file, print out the minimum value for that file

## Invoke the script

```
gawk -f min.awk *.dat
```

## Update

After reviewing my script, I duplicated code which I can eliminate by combining the two blocks:

```
BEGIN {
    print "file number Column 1 column2"
}

FNR == 1 || $2 < min{
    min = $2;
    first = $1
    second = $2
}

ENDFILE {
    # Extract the file number to a[1]
    match(FILENAME, /.*-([0-9]+)\.dat/, a)  
    print a[1], first, second
}
```